# Python simply moving files from one directory to another, works as a Batch file

Tags: python

I am having a frustrating time learning Python and trying to get it to do some simple things.
I have this batch file I would like to emulate, nothing fancy it just moves files from one directory to another simple stuff.

```
xcopy /s K:\PSADMISS\Scans4Slideroom\VikramTestArea G:\A-Admissions\SlideRoom\VikramTestArea\AP_IB
```

As you can see its really simple stuff, just move the files in this one folder on the K: drive to a folder on the G: drive. Tring to rewrite this in Python however has proven to be a frustrating challenge.

so far here is what I have in python:

```
from shutil import copy2
copy2(r"K:\PSADMISS\Scans4Slideroom\VikramTestArea", "G:\A-Admissions\SlideRoom\VikramTestArea\AP_IB")
```

I have even tried this second time but to no avail and a great mess, using Python:

```
#import os
#import shutil
#import copyfile
##os.chdir('C:\\') #Make sure you add your source and destination path below

#src = ("\\aicfs01\A-Admissions\SlideRoom\VikramTestArea\\")
#dst = ("\\aicps01\PSADMISS\Scans4Slideroom\VikramTestArea\\")

#for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
#    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
 #       shutil.copy( dir_src + filename, dir_dst)
  #  print(filename)

from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(r"K:\PSADMISS\Scans4Slideroom\VikramTestArea", "Admissions\SlideRoom\VikramTestArea\AP_IB")

#"G:\A-Admissions\SlideRoom\VikramTestArea\AP_IB"
```

Either way I am getting the same error in python which is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\vmedhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\SlideRoomKtoG.py", line 15, in 
> copyfile(r"K:\PSADMISS\Scans4Slideroom\VikramTestArea", "Admissions\SlideRoom\VikramTestArea\AP_IB")
> File "C:\Users\vmedhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 259, in copyfile
> with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'K:\PSADMISS\Scans4Slideroom\VikramTestArea'

I keep getting this Permission Error, Even though I know for a fact this works because the batch file works. How can I get python to at least emulate this batch file? its one line of code but it seems really annoying for Python to be this frustrating.

Comment: Is your question about using `xcopy` or a `batch-file`? What have either to do with `shutil.copy`/`copyfile`. If your question is nothing to do with the batch file code, please remove it and the unnecessary [[tag:batch-file]] tag.

Comment: sorry no, the batch file I wrote is just to show what I want it to do and that it works as a batch file. this is more an exercise in python learning.